# Xcode uibutton pressed feedback

Tags: xcode, image, button

I have a number of UIButtons in my app. They are of type custom and are filled with images downloaded from the web. On some pages, when I press a button, it goes darker and so the user knows it has been pressed. On other pages though, nothing happens, and it can sometimes feel like the app is not responding to the user's touch. Is there a way to hard code feedback on button pressed?

Comment: How do you create the buttons? In code or in interface builder?

Comment: I've done it all in interface builder

Answer (score 0):

UIButton has a property `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`, which can be set to `YES` in order to provide some basic feedback (the image is drawn lighter when the button is highlighted).

By setting `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` to `YES` you can get a small highlight indicating a touch on the button.

Other than that you can set different images for different states via `- setImage:forState:` and `- setBackgroundImage:forState:`, e.g. for `UIControlStateHighlighted` or `UIControlStateSelected`.